# What is a good way to recyle views in a ListView from a Firebase Database

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, baseadapter, android-recyclerview

**Objective:** I have a `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter` I want to populate with values from my Firebase Database.

This is my `BaseAdapter` I named **MessagesAdapter.java:**

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    boolean showMoreClicked = false;

    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            // set image based on selected text

            holder.message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
            holder.showMoreBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_show_more);
            holder.datetime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ride_time);

            itemView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();

        final Message msg = messages.get(position);
        /* editing item views */
        holder.datetime.setText(msg.getDatetime());
        holder.message.setText(msg.getContent());
        holder.showMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "All Message: "+msg.getContent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showMoreClicked = !showMoreClicked;
            }
        });

        DatabaseReference profileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("profile");
        profileRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Profile sender = dataSnapshot.child(msg.getSender_id()+"").getValue(Profile.class);

                ViewHolder h = new ViewHolder();

                h.userImg = parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_image);
                h.userName = parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.tv_sender_name);
                h.userName.setText(sender.getFirstname()+" "+sender.getLastname()); /*** Error shows up here ***/

                getImageFromDB(sender.getPicpath(), h.userImg);

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView userImg;
        TextView userName;
        TextView datetime;
        TextView message;
        Button showMoreBtn;

    }

    private void getImageFromDB(String firebasePath, ImageView imageView) {
        StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://iveridemap.appspot.com")
                .child(firebasePath);

        // Load the image using Glide
        Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) // cannot resolve method using!
                .load(mStorageRef)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

This adapter is used to fetch messages sent to the current user from firebase and show them in my `ListView`.

I instantiate this `BaseAdapter` and `ListView` inside a fragment I called **MessagesFragment.java:**

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    boolean showMoreClicked = false;

    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            // set image based on selected text

            holder.message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
            holder.showMoreBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_show_more);
            holder.datetime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ride_time);

            itemView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();

        final Message msg = messages.get(position);
        /* editing item views */
        holder.datetime.setText(msg.getDatetime());
        holder.message.setText(msg.getContent());
        holder.showMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "All Message: "+msg.getContent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showMoreClicked = !showMoreClicked;
            }
        });

        DatabaseReference profileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("profile");
        profileRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Profile sender = dataSnapshot.child(msg.getSender_id()+"").getValue(Profile.class);

                ViewHolder h = new ViewHolder();

                h.userImg = parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_image);
                h.userName = parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.tv_sender_name);
                h.userName.setText(sender.getFirstname()+" "+sender.getLastname());

                getImageFromDB(sender.getPicpath(), h.userImg);

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView userImg;
        TextView userName;
        TextView datetime;
        TextView message;
        Button showMoreBtn;

    }

    private void getImageFromDB(String firebasePath, ImageView imageView) {
        StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://iveridemap.appspot.com")
                .child(firebasePath);

        // Load the image using Glide
        Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) // cannot resolve method using!
                .load(mStorageRef)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I scroll down my `ListView` my code returns a `NullPointerException` at the line:

```
h.userName.setText(sender.getFirstname()+" "+sender.getLastname());
```

In the `BaseAdapter`, I pointed it out in the code above. Apprently something is wrong with initiating my profile instance I fetch from Firebase.

**More Info:** This error doesn't show up when there is fewer items in the list and I don't have to scroll down..

I am ready to post more code upon demand, if anyone needs to see my XML file or database structure just say so!

Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a **RecyclerView**, to use firebase items there is some great libraries to make everything more simple

Here is a great library to parcel your items

> compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'

With parceler you can make your activity like this example

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.Query;

import org.parceler.Parcels;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String SAVED_ADAPTER_ITEMS = "SAVED_ADAPTER_ITEMS";
    private final static String SAVED_ADAPTER_KEYS = "SAVED_ADAPTER_KEYS";

    private Query mQuery;
    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MyItem> mAdapterItems;
    private ArrayList<String> mAdapterKeys;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handleInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        setupFirebase();
        setupRecyclerview();
    }

    // Restoring the item list and the keys of the items: they will be passed to the adapter
    private void handleInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(SAVED_ADAPTER_ITEMS) &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(SAVED_ADAPTER_KEYS)) {
            mAdapterItems = Parcels.unwrap(savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_ADAPTER_ITEMS));
            mAdapterKeys = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SAVED_ADAPTER_KEYS);
        } else {
            mAdapterItems = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
            mAdapterKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void setupFirebase() {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        String firebaseLocation = getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_location);
        mQuery = new Firebase(firebaseLocation);
    }

    private void setupRecyclerview() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(mQuery, MyItem.class, mAdapterItems, mAdapterKeys);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Saving the list of items and keys of the items on rotation
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(SAVED_ADAPTER_ITEMS, Parcels.wrap(mMyAdapter.getItems()));
        outState.putStringArrayList(SAVED_ADAPTER_KEYS, mMyAdapter.getKeys());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMyAdapter.destroy();
    }
}
```

Here is the item Model

```
import org.parceler.Parcel;

@Parcel
public class MyItem {

    String name;
    long age;

    public MyItem() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder, MyItem> {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewAge;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
            textViewAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_age);
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(Query query, @Nullable ArrayList<MyItem> items,
                     @Nullable ArrayList<String> keys) {
        super(query, items, keys);
    }

    @Override public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItem item = getItem(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.textViewAge.setText(String.valueOf(item.getAge()));
    }

    @Override protected void itemAdded(MyItem item, String key, int position) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "Added a new item to the adapter.");
    }

    @Override protected void itemChanged(MyItem oldItem, MyItem newItem, String key, int position) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "Changed an item.");
    }

    @Override protected void itemRemoved(MyItem item, String key, int position) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "Removed an item from the adapter.");
    }

    @Override protected void itemMoved(MyItem item, String key, int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "Moved an item.");
    }
}
```

And here is the adapter that is extending the main adapter so it can work with firebase

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android.
 * <p>
 * This class is a generic way of backing an Android RecyclerView with a Firebase location.
 * It handles all of the child events at the given Firebase location.
 * It marshals received data into the given class type.
 * Extend this class and provide an implementation of the abstract methods, which will notify when
 * the adapter list changes.
 * <p>
 * This class also simplifies the management of configuration change (e.g.: device rotation)
 * allowing the restore of the list.
 *
 * @param <T> The class type to use as a model for the data contained in the children of the
 *            given Firebase location
 */
public abstract class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private Query mQuery;
    private ArrayList<T> mItems;
    private ArrayList<String> mKeys;

    /**
     * @param query The Firebase location to watch for data changes.
     *              Can also be a slice of a location, using some combination of
     *              <code>limit()</code>, <code>startAt()</code>, and <code>endAt()</code>.
     */
    public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Query query) {
        this(query, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * @param query The Firebase location to watch for data changes.
     *              Can also be a slice of a location, using some combination of
     *              <code>limit()</code>, <code>startAt()</code>, and <code>endAt()</code>.
     * @param items List of items that will load the adapter before starting the listener.
     *              Generally null or empty, but this can be useful when dealing with a
     *              configuration change (e.g.: reloading the adapter after a device rotation).
     *              Be careful: keys must be coherent with this list.
     * @param keys  List of keys of items that will load the adapter before starting the listener.
     *              Generally null or empty, but this can be useful when dealing with a
     *              configuration change (e.g.: reloading the adapter after a device rotation).
     *              Be careful: items must be coherent with this list.
     */
    public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Query query,
                                   @Nullable ArrayList<T> items,
                                   @Nullable ArrayList<String> keys) {
        this.mQuery = query;
        if (items != null && keys != null) {
            this.mItems = items;
            this.mKeys = keys;
        } else {
            mItems = new ArrayList<T>();
            mKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        query.addChildEventListener(mListener);
    }

    private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            if (!mKeys.contains(key)) {
                T item = getConvertedObject(dataSnapshot);
                int insertedPosition;
                if (previousChildName == null) {
                    mItems.add(0, item);
                    mKeys.add(0, key);
                    insertedPosition = 0;
                } else {
                    int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                    int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                    if (nextIndex == mItems.size()) {
                        mItems.add(item);
                        mKeys.add(key);
                    } else {
                        mItems.add(nextIndex, item);
                        mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                    }
                    insertedPosition = nextIndex;
                }
                notifyItemInserted(insertedPosition);
                itemAdded(item, key, insertedPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            if (mKeys.contains(key)) {
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
                T oldItem = mItems.get(index);
                T newItem = getConvertedObject(dataSnapshot);

                mItems.set(index, newItem);

                notifyItemChanged(index);
                itemChanged(oldItem, newItem, key, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            if (mKeys.contains(key)) {
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
                T item = mItems.get(index);

                mKeys.remove(index);
                mItems.remove(index);

                notifyItemRemoved(index);
                itemRemoved(item, key, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
            T item = getConvertedObject(dataSnapshot);
            mItems.remove(index);
            mKeys.remove(index);
            int newPosition;
            if (previousChildName == null) {
                mItems.add(0, item);
                mKeys.add(0, key);
                newPosition = 0;
            } else {
                int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                if (nextIndex == mItems.size()) {
                    mItems.add(item);
                    mKeys.add(key);
                } else {
                    mItems.add(nextIndex, item);
                    mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                }
                newPosition = nextIndex;
            }
            notifyItemMoved(index, newPosition);
            itemMoved(item, key, index, newPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur.");
        }

    };

    @Override
    public abstract ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    @Override
    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position);

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mItems != null) ? mItems.size() : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Clean the adapter.
     * ALWAYS call this method before destroying the adapter to remove the listener.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        mQuery.removeEventListener(mListener);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of items of the adapter: can be useful when dealing with a configuration
     * change (e.g.: a device rotation).
     * Just save this list before destroying the adapter and pass it to the new adapter (in the
     * constructor).
     *
     * @return the list of items of the adapter
     */
    public ArrayList<T> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of keys of the items of the adapter: can be useful when dealing with a
     * configuration change (e.g.: a device rotation).
     * Just save this list before destroying the adapter and pass it to the new adapter (in the
     * constructor).
     *
     * @return the list of keys of the items of the adapter
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getKeys() {
        return mKeys;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item in the specified position
     *
     * @param position Position of the item in the adapter
     * @return the item
     */
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the item in the adapter
     *
     * @param item Item to be searched
     * @return the position in the adapter if found, -1 otherwise
     */
    public int getPositionForItem(T item) {
        return mItems != null && mItems.size() > 0 ? mItems.indexOf(item) : -1;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the searched item is in the adapter
     *
     * @param item Item to be searched
     * @return true if the item is in the adapter, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean contains(T item) {
        return mItems != null && mItems.contains(item);
    }

    /**
     * ABSTRACT METHODS THAT MUST BE IMPLEMENTED BY THE EXTENDING ADAPTER.
     */

    /**
     * Called after an item has been added to the adapter
     *
     * @param item     Added item
     * @param key      Key of the added item
     * @param position Position of the added item in the adapter
     */
    protected void itemAdded(T item, String key, int position) {

    }

    /**
     * Called after an item changed
     *
     * @param oldItem  Old version of the changed item
     * @param newItem  Current version of the changed item
     * @param key      Key of the changed item
     * @param position Position of the changed item in the adapter
     */
    protected void itemChanged(T oldItem, T newItem, String key, int position) {

    }

    /**
     * Called after an item has been removed from the adapter
     *
     * @param item     Removed item
     * @param key      Key of the removed item
     * @param position Position of the removed item in the adapter
     */
    protected void itemRemoved(T item, String key, int position) {

    }

    /**
     * Called after an item changed position
     *
     * @param item        Moved item
     * @param key         Key of the moved item
     * @param oldPosition Old position of the changed item in the adapter
     * @param newPosition New position of the changed item in the adapter
     */
    protected void itemMoved(T item, String key, int oldPosition, int newPosition) {

    }

    /**
     * Converts the data snapshot to generic object
     *
     * @param snapshot Result
     * @return Data converted
     */
    protected T getConvertedObject(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.getValue(getGenericClass());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a class reference from generic T.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Class<T> getGenericClass() {
        return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

}
```

Useful links:

[Generic Firebase recyclerview list for Android](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I didn't answer sooner I took a week off.
This seems good except that I dont know how to set it all up for a fragment not an activity

Comment: how to generate the com.firebase.client stuff? which dependency shall I use in the gradle??